# ASP.NET MVC 3 model binding of complex object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

Considering MVC model binding of complex objects in general. Will the normal model binding of a complex object fail if there exists a property for which there is no matching form value?

Does anyone have a concise description of the model binding algorithm?

Comment: Could you put your view, model and controller please?

Comment: It's open source, you can look up exactly how it works.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a controller parameter which is a class, the `DefaultModelBinder` will try to create an instance of it and fill the properties with data from the request.

Even when there is not a single value for any property, it will create the object and pass it to your action method.

As stated in the comments, you can download the source of the MVC framework (look for the class `DefaultModelBinder`) or use a tool like reflector so take a look at the source.

If you have a specific problem, please post some code.